# Bitwise operation: fitsBits function

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have seen a few other implementations of this function on this site, but I'm curious if someone can help me figure out why this implementation isn't working:

```
//fitsBits: return 1 if x can be represented as an n-bit, two's complement integer.  
//1<=n<=32 
//Examples: fitsBits(5,3)=0, fitsBits(-4,3)=1
//legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>
//Max ops: 15

    int fitsBits(int x, int n) {
        int mask = ~(1<<31);
        return !(((x>>1)&mask)>>(~(~n+2)+1));
    }
```

So you can follow my logic a little, I shift x one to the right, which could potentially expose an extra 1 (arithmetic shift).  So I create a mask to make sure it becomes a zero before shifting the rest of x.  Originally I would need to shift x n times to the right, and if there were any left-over 1s, it would signify that x won't fit in n-bits.  Since I've moved x to the right by one bit, I now need to move it n-1 times.

The result I get is:

```
ERROR: Test fitsBits(2147483647[0x7fffffff],31[0x1f]) failed...
...Gives 1[0x1]. Should be 0[0x0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've written looks like C, in which right shifts for -ve numbers are "implementation defined", so may or may not be arithmetic shifts.  (For left shifts things are even worse, the result for -ve values is undefined.)  So, it is best to do all shifty things unsigned.

For 2's complement, n bits... a +ve number must be all '0' from bit(n-1) upwards, and for a -ve number must be all '1'... hence, and in C assuming all unsigned 32-bit integers (with no padding!)...

```
m = UINT_MAX << (n - 1) ;    // bits from n-1 upwards
q = - (x >> 31) ;            // all sign bits, assuming 32bit integers
return ((x ^ q) & m) == 0 ;
```

---

Added later...

...I confess I did not struggle to try to work out what your code:

```
  int fitsBits(int x, int n)
  {
    int mask = ~(1<<31);
    return !(((x>>1)&mask)>>(~(~n+2)+1));
  }
```

might be trying to do (given the difficulties of shifting `int` values).  However, assuming that the `mask` ends up as `0x7FFFFFFF`, and that `(x>>1)` is either a simple shift or an arithmetic one, then:

- `(x>>1)&mask` is a simple shift of 1, as in `((unsigned)x)>>1`
- `~n+2` is `~n+1+1` is `-n+1` (since we assume 2's complement)
- and `~(~n+2)+1` is `-(~n+2)` is `-(-n+1)` is `n-1`
- so, `(((x>>1)&mask)>>(~(~n+2)+1))` is `(((unsigned)x)>>1)>>(n-1)` is (drum roll)...

  ... `((unsigned)x)>>n`

...which is all the bits which are to be discarded in order to store `x` in an `n` bit field.

If you were wanting to test whether `x` fits in an *unsigned* `n` bit field, then `(((unsigned)x)>>n) == 0`, would do the trick.

To test whether *signed* `x` fits into a *signed* `n` bit field, you need to worry about the value of `((unsigned)x)>>(n-1)`, which must be zero or `0xFFFFFFFF>>(n-1)`, depending on the sign of `x`.

(I note, in passing, that the requirement is for `1<=n<=32`... if `n=1`, we have just the sign bit, so we can represent numbers in the range -1..0, which looks peculiar, but is nevertheless correct.)